# Trigger event of select2 for testing in RSpec

Tags: javascript, rspec, capybara

I have a select2 on my page which has the following onchange event:

```
$("#product_menu_category_id").on("change", function(e) {
  $.ajax( {
  url: '/product_prices',
  data: {id: e.val, product_id: <%= @product.id %> },
  success:  function(data){ data }
  })
})
```

and use the follow helper function to set a value during testing:

```
def set_select2_value(index, id, value)
  "$('.select2-container').each(function(index) {if (index == " + index.to_s + ") $(this).select2('data', {id: '" + id.to_s + "', text: '"+ value + "'})});"
end
```

This works perfect for all the select2 controls that don't have a onchange trigger hooked to them.

How can I set the value during my RSpec (capybara) tests and also trigger any onchange event (if one would be present)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a way to do so, you need to use {triggerChange:true}) and also set the value on the offscreen select, not the select2:

```
"$('select.select2-offscreen').each(function(index) {if (index == " + index.to_s + ") $(this).select2('val', '" + id.to_s + "', {triggerChange:true}); });"
```